# Is there a traffic parameter on Terraform azurerm_app_service_slot?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service

I am creating a module to standarize app service slots in Azure. Problem is I cannot seem to be able to configure percentage of traffic for the slot.

Any idea of how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a traffic parameter on Terraform azurerm_app_service_slot?

You can use the **reroutePercentage** parameter to configure percentage of traffic for the slot.

```
reroutePercentage - number
```

Used for the Percentage of the traffic which will be redirected to `ActionHostName`.

Comment: Is this part of the site_config block? could you please give me some background on where this parameters are being used?